# Text width of a QPlainTextEdit

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, fonts

I have a QPlainTextEdit widget that fills a portion of my window. The user can resize the window, therefore the area consumed by the QPlainTextEdit widget can vary.

I would like to know how I can determine, at runtime, what are the maximum number of characters I can write to the text area before the horizontal scroll bar will appear.

I am displaying columns of text that I will truncate to a maximum per column width. However, I only want to truncate columns if the total untruncated width of all columns will produce a scroll bar.

In other words, if the total text doesn't fill the text area horizontally, there's no value in truncating any part of said text.

Answer (score 1):

Use [QFontMetrics::width](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfontmetrics.html#width) to help figure out the size of your text

Comment: This gives me the inverse of what I would like. I would rather the formatter doesn't have to know things like fonts, pixels and the width of the display. Any suggestions?